# Is there a way to make an invisible button in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I found ways to hide something after pressing a button, but what I would like to do is having an invisible button that can still be pushed. A secret button of some sort, using Tkinter. It doesn't need to do anything yet

Comment: maybe a canvas with transparent color and on click method?

Comment: Invisible UI elements have a tendency to ignore input events, so they usually cannot be "pushed". You could get away with a fully transparent button, though, but IIRC Tkinter colors do not support an alpha channel.

Comment: Or, if transparent color is not an option, just the same color as the background.

Comment: Yeah I'll see if I can try it this way, thank you

Comment: @tobias_k I'll go with this solution, as it seems to be the easiest and works for what I need to do with it. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an invisible button to register a secret click Simply bind `<1>` to the root window and it will register whenever you click on anything (unless you click on some other widget that is listening for that event). You can then check the coordinates of the click to see where the use clicked.